# .htaccess redirect to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm tying to set up the scenario, if someone visits **website.com/blog/** they are redirected to **blog.website.com**.

I used this code in my .htaccess file to achieve some other redirection (from .net to .com) previously:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.|blog.)?website.net(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It may also be relevant that I have an **ErrorDocument 404** in my apache configuration file.

To solve my my problem I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.|blog.)?website.net(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website(.com|.net)/blog/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog.website.com/ [L]
```

This code however is not working. My error document is still handling the request (the /blog/ directory doesn't exist). I tried moving this new code above the ErrorDocument in the apache conf file, but the same thing occurred.

It's no doubt a syntactical error, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `webiste.com` site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.website.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 12):

in the .htaccess file in the root of your website.com directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ http://blog.website.com/$1
```